# Instance Turtle Object Arguments in vain

Tags: python, python-turtle

Basically, my intention was to create a class to easily create instances of turtle objects rather than copy-pasting code. However, as of now, I have no idea why the arguments are being ignored. I could not find anything to mitigate this. I am very new to coding and sorry if the reason is blindingly obvious I have been trying things out for several hours now to no avail.

This is part of my code that includes my issue:

```
import turtle

wind = turtle.Screen()
 
wind.title("Turtle") 

wind.bgcolor('#1c2e4a')  
wind.setup(width=800, height=600)  
wind.tracer(0) 


class Audience:

    def __init__(self, setheading, goto):
        self.turtle = turtle.Turtle()
        self.turtle.speed(0)
        self.turtle.shape("turtle")
        self.turtle.color('#bab86c')
        self.turtle.penup()
        self.turtle.goto = goto
        self.turtle.setheading = setheading
        self.turtle.shapesize(stretch_wid=2, stretch_len=2)


audience1 = Audience(180, (0, -260))

while True:

wind.update()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the arguments are being ignored"? You're never using `audience1` in this code. What behavior do you expect, and what is actually happening?

Comment: Thanks for responding! What I mean by arguments is the inputs corresponding to the parameters setheading, and goto for the function defined in the class. If you run the code right now you would see that the turtle/audience1 is in the centre of the screen where it should be on the bottom of the window given the argument goto(0,-260). Also the direction it should face is off, it is facing the standard setheading direction. Hence I am concluding the arguments are being ignored somehow. Is this in anyway clear?

Comment: `turtle.goto` and `turtle.setheading` are methods; not plain attributes that you overwrite. With this code, you're overwriting the methods with the values. You mean `self.turtle.goto(goto); self.turtle.setheading(setheading)`.

Comment: Brilliant thanks a lot! Pardon my ignorance I am new to this stuff. Still trying to figure things out.

Comment: No problem. When in doubt though, [read the manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.goto). You'd see what it's a method, and see examples of how it's used (although, in that particular case, the example is for `setpos`, not `goto`, but they appear to be the same method).

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to be complicated by the fact that `Audience` *contains* a turtle instance when it might be simpler for `Audience` to *be* a `Turtle` subclass:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

class Audience(Turtle):

    def __init__(self, heading, position):
        super().__init__(visible=False)

        self.speed('fastest')
        self.shape('turtle')
        self.color('#bab86c')
        self.penup()
        self.goto(position)
        self.setheading(heading)
        self.shapesize(stretch_wid=2, stretch_len=2)

        self.showturtle()

screen = Screen()
screen.title('Turtle')
screen.bgcolor('#1c2e4a')
screen.setup(width=800, height=600)

audience1 = Audience(180, (0, -260))

screen.mainloop()
```

Of course, as @Carcigenicate comments (+1) you're setting properties when you should be invoking methods, and you're redefining existing names.  And avoid that `while True:` and `update()` model, you're heading the wrong direction.  Consider `ontimer()`, and other events, instead.

Comment: Thank you for your elaboration and advice, I will take it to heart. I was wondering if there were better ways of running this. Very helpful!